# Jump to anchor in overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul id="the-list" style="overflow:hidden;height:100px;>
    <li><a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link3" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="link4" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a id="link5" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a id="link6" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    <li><a id="link7" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
    <li><a id="link8" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
    <li><a id="link8" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
<ul>
<a href="">more</a> <a href="">less</a>
```

The div above shows the first three links. When selecting  more I want to to show 4-6. It doesn't need to do any smooth scrolling. Found a couple similar examples on stackoverflow but they didnt involve a link outside of the ul like this. Wondering what the simplest option is. Also as a bonus would love a less button that would undo the more. Such as if it advanced to show the next three clicking less would go back 3?

Can use jquery if necessary. Would like to keep it as simply as positive. Thank you for any ideas, I'll keep researching in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I got you right, but if you want to change visible content of `#the-list` (show next 3 items and hide previous 3), than here's a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hzonoyg0/

Comment: YES! That's exactly what I was looking for but was having a challenge describing it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this by changing the height css value.
I tested it in JsFiddle, but it doesn't run in the "Run Code Snippet" of stackoverflow.

```js
var ydelta = 60;

window.more = function () {
 var list = document.getElementById("the-list");
  list.style.height = '' + (parseInt(list.style.height) + ydelta) + 'px';
};

window.less = function () {
 var list = document.getElementById("the-list");
  list.style.height = '' + (parseInt(list.style.height) - ydelta) + 'px';
};
```

```html
<ul id="the-list" style="overflow:hidden;height:60px;">
    <li><a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link3" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="link4" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a id="link5" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a id="link6" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    <li><a id="link7" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
    <li><a id="link8" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
    <li><a id="link8" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:more();">more</a> 
<a href="javascript:less();">less</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested in my code and clicking more simply appears to show more of the existing list. Rather than having it show just the next grouping. So if it shows 1-3 by default, then clicking more would show 4-6, and clicking less would show 1-3 again. etc. Is it working properly that way on your machine?

Comment: No, i misunderstood what you wanted.